# how to add JS and CSS tags from module without using header hook

Tags: javascript, css, module, tags, prestashop

is there any way to add JS and CSS tags just for the page where the module is contained?

If i use the code snippet

```
$this->context->controller->addjs('js/file.js', 'all');
```

in the "**hookHeader**", the script is added for the whole website (index, cms pages, etc.) where hook is used.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a js file only in page product and category for example, you can do this :

```
public function hookDisplayHeader($params)
{
    $allowed_controllers = array('product', 'category');
    $_controller = $this->context->controller;
    if (isset($_controller->php_self) && in_array($_controller->php_self, $allowed_controllers)) {
        $this->context->controller->addCss($this->_path . 'css/front.css', 'all');
        $this->context->controller->addJs($this->_path . 'js/front.js');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes  you can do it easily. 
What you need to do it to call addJs or addCss in the desired hook function only. For example, if you are hooking your module at left column on certain pages only, then if you call

```
$this->context->controller->addjs('js/file.js', 'all');
```

at your hookLeftColumn (what ever the method name is nowadays :P ), then that js or css file will be only used when that module is displayed.

Or you can just place that css / js file directly in the template.

Comment: I dont know why your solution doesn't work for me. That my code snippet.

public function hookGalleryHook($params) {
$this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path) . 'js/gallery.js');
$this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path) . 'css/style.css', 'all');

return $this->display(__FILE__, 'gallery.tpl', $this->getCacheId());

}

Answer (score 1):

If your module will appear on specific pages, you can define "Exceptions" - the same that can be defined via Back Office > Modules > Positions > Transplant a module.

This way the hookDisplayHeader for that module will not be even executed and no CSS and JS files will be added. This is a better solution from a performance view point.

Comment: nice, +1 .. can you be more specific plz?

Comment: Everything is explained at the "Transplant a module" page: http://prntscr.com/2pqk7n

Comment: perfect, I agree this is the cleaner way